# search a string and move the whole line above to the last

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with more than thousands of lines.

```
=========================
/dir1/dir2/dir2/
file1 A B C /dirsource file1
==========================
/dir4/dir2/dir4/dir5/
file2 A B C /dirsource file2
===========================
/dir1/dir2/dir2/
file3 A B C /dirsource file3
===========================
```

I want to format the lines to like this:

```
=========================
/dir1/dir2/dir2/ file1 A B C /dirsource file1
==========================
/dir4/dir2/dir4/dir5/ file2 A B C /dirsource file2
===========================
/dir1/dir2/dir2/ file3 A B C /dirsource file3
===========================
```

I can't get the exact regexp on notepad++

Could anyone experience with notepad++ can lighten me up on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!=)\R(?!=+)`
- Replace with: `A SPACE`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!=)      # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't a = before
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(?!=+)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't = after)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. This is 101% solution that I need and you save my 100 hours of experimenting this. thank you very much!